# Selecting latest record from query result

Tags: sql

I have below `SQL query` which fetches record from 3 tables based on system date.
    Table service_request has multiple records, now I want to fetch the latest row based on service_request table ID.

Given `query`, provides 12 records, out of 12, only 3 SR.ID are unique and I would like to fetch only those 3 in my result.

```
SELECT SR.ID, BR.SVC_PT_UDC_ID, D.UDC_ID, D.SUB_TYPE, SR.TYPE_CD, SR.SUB_TYPE_CD, BR.REQUEST_STATUS,BR.EXTNL_BILLING_REQUEST_ID,BR.INSERT_TIME
FROM BILLING_REQUEST BR 
JOIN SERVICE_REQUEST SR
ON BR.SVC_PT_ID = SR.SVC_PT_ID
JOIN DEVICE D
ON SR.DEVICE_ID = D.ID
WHERE 
REQUEST_SRC = 'DDSWebServiceImportAdapter' 
AND TRUNC(BR.INSERT_TIME) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) -1
AND (SR.TYPE_CD != 'Meter Service' AND SR.TYPE_CD != 'RMM');
```

Comment: Please add the tag for the DBMS you are using

Comment: What is the data type of the ID you are using? and also if possible add the desing of your table what other fields you've used.

Comment: Is this Oracle? If so, which version? As of 12c you can use `FETCH FIRST`.

Comment: Seems to be Oracle: sysdate.

Comment: Hi,
I am using Oracle 11c (tool SQL Developer)

Comment: Hi,
I am using Oracle 11c (tool SQL Developer)
Data Type of ID in all is Number

Here is my updated question

I have below query which fetches record from 4 tables based on system date.

BILLING_REQUEST table has 4 records for sysdate-1 and I need all of these to be present
But SERVICE_REQUEST table gives multiple records, total 40, in my final result I need only 4 records which correspond to BILLING_REQUEST table

Comment: TABLE STRUCTURE

Billing Request TABLE
ID (PK)       EXTNL_BILLING_REQUEST_ID(STRING)     SVC_PT_UDC_ID(STRING)      SVC_PT_ID(FK)   INSERT_TIME(TIMESTAMP)

SVC_PT TABLE
ID (PK)      UDC_ID(STRING)    INSERT_TIME(TIMESTAMP)

SVC_PT_DEVICE_REL
ID (PK)     SVC_PT_ID (FK)     DEVICE_ID (FK)    EFF_START_TIME(TIMESTAMP)  

DEVICE TABLE
ID (PK)     UDC_ID(STRING)    TYPE(STRING)     INSERT_TIME(TIMESTAMP)


SERVICE_REQUEST TABLE
ID (PK)    TYPE_CD(STRING)    SUB_TYPE_CD (STRING)    SVC_PT_ID(FK)   DEVICE_ID (FK)

Answer (score 0):

```
Modified question, 

Hi,

I have below query which fetches record from 5 tables based on system date.

BILLING_REQUEST table has 4 records for sysdate-1 and I need all of these to be present
But SERVICE_REQUEST table gives multiple records, total 40, in my final result I need only 4 records which correspond to BILLING_REQUEST table

TABLE STRUCTURE

Billing Request TABLE
ID (PK)       EXTNL_BILLING_REQUEST_ID(STRING)     SVC_PT_UDC_ID(STRING)      SVC_PT_ID(FK)   STATUS    INSERT_TIME(TIMESTAMP)
-- Contains 4 records

SVC_PT TABLE
ID (PK)      UDC_ID(STRING)    INSERT_TIME(TIMESTAMP)
-- Contains 4 records

SVC_PT_DEVICE_REL
ID (PK)     SVC_PT_ID (FK)     DEVICE_ID (FK)    EFF_START_TIME(TIMESTAMP)  
-- Contains 4 records

DEVICE TABLE
ID (PK)     UDC_ID(STRING)    TYPE(STRING)     INSERT_TIME(TIMESTAMP)
-- Contains 4 records


SERVICE_REQUEST TABLE
ID (PK)    TYPE_CD(STRING)    SUB_TYPE_CD (STRING)    SVC_PT_ID(FK)   DEVICE_ID (FK)
-- Contains 40 records (only 4 unique SVC_PT_ID are present in this table, so need to fetch the 4 latest ID which corresponds to 4 unique SVC_PT_ID)

QUERY BEING USED
SELECT SR.ID, BR.SVC_PT_UDC_ID, D.UDC_ID, D.SUB_TYPE, 
SR.TYPE_CD, SR.SUB_TYPE_CD, 
BR.REQUEST_STATUS,BR.EXTNL_BILLING_REQUEST_ID,BR.INSERT_TIME
FROM BILLING_REQUEST BR
JOIN SVC_PT_DEVICE_REL SDR
ON BR.SVC_PT_ID = SDR.SVC_PT_ID
JOIN DEVICE D
ON SDR.DEVICE_ID = D.ID
JOIN SERVICE_REQUEST SR
ON BR.SVC_PT_ID = SR.SVC_PT_ID
WHERE 
REQUEST_SRC = 'DDSWebServiceImportAdapter' 
AND TRUNC(BR.INSERT_TIME) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) -6
AND (SR.TYPE_CD != 'Meter Service' AND SR.TYPE_CD != 'RMM')
```